# DTE ItemOperations.NewFile(...) for VS2010 Addin

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

in this code, in my addin that I'm attmepting to wrie for Vs2010

```
    _applicationObject.ItemOperations.NewFile( "General\\Text File", FileName, Constants.vsViewKindCode );
```

The first paramter is defined as the virtual location for the file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.itemoperations.newfile(v=vs.80).aspx

Is it just a String with the path, starting at the root of my soloution?

If so if I want to put a file in /+".CV", how can i do that?

I read some where to create a file while recoriding a macro, and look at the guts of the macro.
that said @"Visual C# Items\Code\Class".

but when I run that is says that template can't be found.

Thanks,

Eric-

Answer (score 2):

I actually used this

```
DTE.ItemOperations.AddNewItem("General\Text File")
```

which reformed from what I got from the macro editor and put together this

```
DTEObj.ItemOperations.AddNewItem(@"Visual C# Items\WPF\User Control (WPF)", filename + ".xaml");
```

So in your case give this a try

```
DTEObj.ItemOperations.AddNewItem("General\Text File");
```